# How do I reference a .js or .css file from a single page on BigCommerce?

Tags: bigcommerce

I have a photo gallery that has it's own .css and .js file. I'd like to be able to add those to only the gallery page. They server no purpose anywhere else on the site. How I do this in BigCommerce? I can't seem to find the gallery page I created in their file system.

Comment: can you clarify what you mean by gallery page? Like the category?

Comment: A custom gallery page. Not part of the main BigCommerce system.

Comment: so a custom web page template?

Comment: Well, I created a page through the system. It's using the template. I've been trying to update the HTMLHead without any luck. I'd prefer to only apply the javascript and styles to just the one page.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, it's not considered best practice, but if you are using the [HTML5 Doctype](https://www.w3.org/TR/html51/syntax.html#the-doctype) specification, e.g:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

Your css doesn't need to be in the  of your site. You could add your link to the top of your custom gallery page. If you're adding them through the html editor while editing a page, I believe a relative file path will work for those assets, such as:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/template/Styles/yourfile.css" />
<script src="/template/Styles/yourfile.js"></script>
```

If you create a custom page template file you can check the documentation on [referencing assets in a theme](https://support.bigcommerce.com/articles/Public/Referencing-Assets-in-a-Theme).
Both files will need to have been uploaded via webdav.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out this is not going to be possible without major edits to the existing CSS but thanks for the help.